# Difficulty scraping some prices off a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Trying to scrape prices off a website but certain prices are crossed out and a new price is shown so I was getting null for those prices. Well, I figured I could set up an if statement in order to get right price well it kind of worked.  But instead of getting the new price I get the crossed out price because the identifiers are the same for both.  Any ideas on how to fix this?  [image: Screenshot of HTML code] [image: html code of not corssed out price]

```
  for game in response.css("tr[class^=deckdbbody]"):

            # Initialize saved_name to the extracted card name
            saved_name  = game.css("a.card_popup::text").extract_first() or saved_name
            # Now call item and set equal to saved_name and strip leading '\n' from output
            item["Card_Name"] = saved_name.strip()
            # Check to see if output is null, in the case that there are two different conditions for one card
            if item["Card_Name"] != None:
                # If not null than store value in saved_name
                saved_name = item["Card_Name"].strip()
            # If null then set null value to previous card name since if there is a null value you should have the same card name twice
            else:
                item["Card_Name"] = saved_name
            # Call item again in order to extract the condition, stock, and price using the corresponding html code from the website
            item["Condition"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_7 a::text").get()
            item["Stock"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_8::text").extract_first()
            item["Price"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_9::text").extract_first()
            if item["Price"] == None:
                item["Price"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_9 span::text").get()

            # Return values
            yield item
```

Comment: Looks like the crossed price has a line-through value in text-decoration css, isn't this the difference between crossed and uncrossed you were looking for?

Comment: @VitorFalcão Yes I already noticed that.  But I cannot figure out where code I should use to scrape necessary data.  Can I scrape the prices based on style or text-decoration? If so how would I do that, never done that before.

Comment: Show me the html for a price not crossed please

Comment: can you supply the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what ended up working

```
if item["Price"] == None:
    item["Price"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_9 span[style*='color:red']::text").get()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to scrape it considering the style tag `style="text-decoration:line-through"` is for the prices you do not want.

For that you could use BeautifulSoup and considering the prices that are not crossed has no style tag:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests as r

response = r.get(url)
soup = bs(response.content)
decks = bs.find_all('td', {'class': 'deckdbbody', 'style': None})
```

Now get the text content inside each one, which is the price:

```py
prices = [d.getText().strip() for d in decks]
```

With your update, I can see you will get unwanted things inside `prices` list because a lot of `td` uses this class and is not even a price, an easy way to fix would be checking if you have a dollar sign in the `.getText()`:

```py
final = []
for price in prices:
    if '$' in price:
        final.append(price)
```

Now `final` only has what you really want.

Comment: Thank you for this but is there a way to do this with Scrapy?  I do not have BeautifulSoup installed and have been using scrapy-splash.  But if not I can always install it.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but that did not work for me.  I posted below what worked for me...